# Trying to write Alien Invasion by the book. While Trying to Group bullets, I get AttributeError

Tags: python, pygame

Following "Python Crash Course" and I'm stuck while trying to group all the bullets on the screen, I Get an `AttributeError`:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/esmai/PycharmProjects/AllienInvasion1/allien_invasion.py", line 27, in <module>
    run_game()
  File "C:/Users/esmai/PycharmProjects/AllienInvasion1/allien_invasion.py", line 24, in run_game
    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
  File "C:\Users\esmai\PycharmProjects\AllienInvasion1\game_functions.py", line 36, in update_screen
    for bullet in bullets.sprite():
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'sprite'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here are the files (as the error only occurred in `alien_invasion.py` and `game_functions.py`, those two will be the first two folders you see followed by `bullet.py`...):

**alien_invasion.py**:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
   
def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    # the .display tells python to set display somehow, duh
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height)
    )
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()

    while True:  
        gf.check_event(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        bullets.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    
run_game()
```

**game_functions.py**:

```
import pygame
import sys
from bullet import Bullet
   
def check_keydown_event(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)
   
def check_keyup_event(event, ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False
  
def check_event(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_event(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_event(event, ship)
  
def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    for bullet in bullets.sprite():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    'the Group AttributeError occurs here as grouping bullets do not have attribute sprite, apparently.'
    ship.blitme()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

**bullet.py**:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, ship, screen):
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0,
                                ai_settings.bullet_width,
                                ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

    def update(self):
        self.y = self.speed_factor
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

**ship.py**:

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        self.screen = screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        self.rect.centerx = self.center

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

**settings.py**:

```
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):

        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 700
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 225, 69, 0

        # For ship Speed
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
```

Comment: Didn't you mean just `for bullet in bullets:`? `bullets` already consists of `sprite`s if that's what you meant there

Comment: That's true, I have tried 'for bullet in bullets:', however after that bullets won't fire and cause another error this time in bullet.py as 'AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect''. @Tomerikoo

Comment: @Rabbid76 In your link it shows that `iter` is also iterating the sprites, so it should either be `bullets.sprites()` or just `bullets`...

Comment: @E_Roj well then maybe you should have asked about **that** error instead. Try to post a [mre], emphasis on the minimal

Comment: I don't know if you got it by now, but I am a complete beginner. Posting this took me almost 30mins, I will check the links you sent me, and for the next time, I will make sure to research a bit more. thanks. @Tomerikoo

Comment: I am guessing that you originally meant to do `for bullet in bullets.sprites()`. I would say that you should try that and ask according to the errors/problems **that** gives you

Comment: You guessed right, the post originally was about that, I fixed the code so I'm on the point with the post (now the same error occurs). [according to the book the code works flawlessly with using `bullets.sprite()`.].

Comment: It is just a typo `bullets.sprite()` -> `bullets.sprites()`. Note a `pygame.Group` has  not method `sprite`, but it has a method [`sprites()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.sprites)

Comment: >>>man i don't know what to say, but thank you, why does it show this now!<<<File "C:\Users\esmai\PycharmProjects\AllienInvasion1\bullet.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
`AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'`

Comment: Your new error is happening because when you're making a new bullet in `check_keydown_event()`, the order of the arguments you're passing in the `Bullet()` call don't match the order of the parameters in the `__init__()` method of `Bullet`. I'm author of PCC, and the version of this game in the second edition of the book is entirely class-based to avoid this issue of passing so many arguments around.

Comment: I'd also point out that you don't always have to copy code word for word from a learning resource. But naming things is important. Functions like `check_events()` are plural for a reason; that function finds all events that might have occurred and processes them. Renaming that to `check_event()` seems insignificant, and it doesn't make any difference if everything works. But when things don't work, the names we choose affects the way we think about our programs. Accurate names are really helpful, and I'd encourage you to think carefully about the names you use.

Comment: @japhyr I admit that I had the greatest joys when I was getting errors, as those errors were the reasons for me to make this Stackoverflow account and join various subreddits, thus seeking helping-hands such yourself(can't believe it). Truly I fear making mistakes and don't want to blame myself for wasting time on something that, obviously, is not on my level, thus leading to dissatisfaction. as Simon Sinek once said "Most people do things based on WHAT not WHY ", I too, apparently, fell into that trap myself. My utmost appreciation to you for the help firstly, and for the feedback foremostly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post here has a couple of problems.

- the biggest problem is that the code was generated from an old edition of the book, as the author of the book stated in the comments.
- next, the problems in this post have stated from the perspective of a newcomer (I). so the main problem occurred from naming the variables wrong or different from a file to another, again stated by the author. So when I redo the project, I nailed it in the head >>boom<<, of course, by changing to the second edition of the Python Crash course.

so what to learn from this.

1. name variables correctly.
2. listen to the author's podcasts, in a podcast he once said that "new programmers buy early editions..." and he was right (check the edition of the book, K?)
3. don't follow the code blindly, change aspects of the code to your tunning.
4. download the resources, it is free but the knowledge in it boils the ocean.
5. thanks for the help, each comment put me on pins and needles. in short thanks.